# AdminJS call backend from component with arguments

Tags: node.js, adminjs

I am trying to call an action with arguments from an AdminJS component. I am uploading files to aws s3.

There is the `api.resourceAction` method that works well for me to call a resource action, but I need to send some strings to the action, is there a more simple way or I have to use fetch with a custom route ? (this is what I am currently using and it works but it is overcomplicated)

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `params` or `data`.

AdminJS ApiClient is just an extension of Axios where `resourceAction`, `recordAction` etc are wrappers around Axios API. So what you can do:

```
api.resourceAction({
  // resourceId and actionName are required by "resourceAction"
  resourceId: 'Image',
  actionName: 'upload',
  // you can add any valid Axios config option too
  params: {
    someParam: 'test'
  },
  data: {
    file: <your file>
  },
  method: 'post'
})
```

`params` will be available in `request.query`, `data` will be available in `request.payload` of your handler function